# Creating a Measure to calculate Percentage in Tableau

Tags: sql-server, tableau-api

Normally in Tableau to calculate % I create a measure and use the below logic;

SUM ([MEASURE_1])/ SUM([MEASURE_2])

However i am trying to get the % when using a measure and an already aggregated measure and I'm getting the below error;

Argument to SUM (an aggregate function is already an aggregation, and cannot be further aggregated.

My percentage is to calculated the % difference between a policy count from table 1 which is a measure. and measure 2 which I had to create to get the count of policies from table 2 as follows; Count([Policy]). I'm using SQL Server database.

Any ideas how i can resolve this issue?

Thanks!

Measure 1 is a count from table 1, the data looks like the following;

[image]

Measure 2  is from table 2, I am creating a count in tableau of the policy number, the data looks like the below;

[image]

The 2 tables join on agent number

Table 1 structure;

```
   [UNIQUEPOL_CNT]
  ,[UNIQUEAGT_CNT]
  ,[VECHICLE_TXT]
  ,[VEHICLE_DESC]
  ,[VEHICLE_CD]
  ,[CODE_DESC]
  ,[POLICY_ID]
  ,[POLICY_NBR]
  ,[STATE_CD]
  ,[AGENT_NBR]
  ,[AGENT_NM]
  ,[PROP_ID]
  ,[WRITTEN_DT]
  ,[PURCHASE_DT]
  ,[SUSP_IND]
  ,[SUSPEND_DT]
  ,[BIND_ID]
  ,[INSURED_NM]
  ,[CHANGEDBY_ID]

table 2 structure;
 
   [REPORT_DT]
  ,[AGENT_NBR]
  ,[TRR_TOTALPIF_CNT]
  ,[TRR_TOTALPON_CNT]
  ,[TRR_TOTALREV_CNT]
  ,[TRR_TOTALERR_CNT]
```

This is the invalid output...

[image]

Comment: I have update my question with the column details from the two different tables, thanks!

Comment: I have added in the table structures, hope this helps.

Comment: Do you want `58/12` as output which is sum(measure1) =58 and count of measure2 = 12?? I am not getting this

Comment: yes, i would like to get  58/12 as output which is sum(measure1) =58 and count of measure2 = 12

Comment: See the answer proposed below! hope it helps

Comment: Refer your added output, can you please attach a complete screenshot, I mean including, rows/columns shelf, data pane, marks card, etc. so that I can understand what you have done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**

I created two datasets to demonstrate you a solution

dataset1

[image]

dataset 2

[image]

Connecting both datasets in Tableau.

[image]

I built a view in tableau as (**Note `policies` field blue color as it has been converted to dimension**)

[image]

Now calculate a field as

```
ATTR({FIXED [Agent code]: count([Policy no])}/[Policies])
```

Adding this to viz gives me

[image]

wherein desired percentages are displayed.

**Note- since the tables have one-to-many relationships fixed statement in respect of measure on lesser side of relationship will also result in same result.**

```
ATTR({FIXED [Agent code]: count([Policy no])}/
{FIXED [Agent code]: AVG([Policies])})
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i need the % for each row per agent number, so i tried using [Measure_1]/{Count([Measure2])}, but the percentage value is not correct, i have put what the incorrect % looks like in my question

Comment: So do you need 144/1521 as first output and others to follow same pattern?

Comment: yes so 144/1521 then next row 102/2820 and then continue for each row, that updated calculation sum(Measure1)/{Fixed [agent] : count([Measure2])} did not give the correct result, it returns the measure 1 value

Comment: See edited solution.  If it still doesn't help, I reiterate that you may have to share a few rows of complete data inputs (both datasets) and desired output in respect of those sample rows only

Comment: Yes thats working for me now! i used ATTR({FIXED [Agent code]: count([Policy no])}/
{FIXED [Agent code]: AVG([Policies])}) to get the result. Thank you so much for your help on this. I am new to Tableau (as you can maybe tell) so I am still finding my way.

Comment: Glad that it helped.  I am still learning and find stackoverflow a great learning tool.  I hope next time you'll put your problem in simple terms i.e. a few lines of input data and expected output in terms of that sample data.  Good luck